# ¿Por qué mi clase sr-only no funciona?

Tags: html, angular, vscode, clase

Este es mi código. Lo que ocurre aquí es que en el label le agregué class="sr-only" para que oculte la palabra Nombre. Sin embargo al revisar en la web, Nombre sigue visible.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>{{titulo}}</h3>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <form class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="nombre" class="sr-only"> Nombre </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"
      class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "nombreInput">
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

He refrescado la pagina, detener e iniciar el servidor pero Nombre sigue ahí y no me aparece ningún error en la consola de Visual-Studio-Code y en Google.

¿Habré instalado algo mal? Ya que es una clase de bootstrap, al instalarlo agregué lo de jquery y popper para instalarlos igualmente así como incluirlos en el arreglo del angular.json.

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para poner un fragmento de código cargando los estilos de _Bootstrap_ y la etiqueta se oculta correctamente.

Comment: Funcionó. Muchísimas gracias. ¿Podrías explicarme qué es, cómo funciona y el por qué? Lo que ocurre es que en mi curso que ando estudiando, en ningún momento agrega lo que editaste, que es: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Además de eso, cuando instalo Bootstrap también noto que a mi profesor se le incluye el archivo de e2e, sin embargo por alguna razón a mi no se me instala ese archivo a pesar de seguir los mismos pasos. Si sabes la respuesta de lo que me sucede pues te lo agradecería.

Comment: Debes instalar _Bootstrap_ y configurarlo en tu proyecto, en la sección `styles`, como se menciona en [este artículo](https://fbellod.medium.com/como-integrar-el-framework-bootstrap-en-un-proyecto-angular-a5d53fa79e03)